# Only one item selecting in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm on Blender 3.4.1 and I have switched from object to edit mode and I can see xray of one item for some reason, and I am unable to edit other items, even if I click on them. It shows that they are selected, but the only item I'm able to edit is the weird one that is xray-ed.

I'm learning Blender so this might be obvious but I'm not sure what it could be

Screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The object which you are editing does not change by selecting a different object. The objects which has the editing symbol next to it (the square with the top-right corner highlighted) indicates the object which you are editing. In this case that's "Cube.001" and in your case "Cilinder.004":

[image]

If you want to change this to another object, simply click on the dot next to the object you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Edit mode does not make objects merge together. While you can go into edit mode on multiple objects at once, you do this by selecting multiple objects, then entering edit mode.

Note that that isn’t really an X-ray view: You can’t see through anything. In edit mode, edges become visible and traced out in black for convenience. When selection mode is set to Vertex, vertices also have dots on them.

This is a pretty basic question. See the Blender manual for more information.

- [Scenes and Objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/index.html)
- [Modeling](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/introduction.html#modes)